# I am not getting printed output of c list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here as you can see I have added this code but I am  not getting output

```
worddictionary = {'kjnkn':4, 'efgrs':6, 'fgesgv':7}
a = list()
b = list()
c = list()
k = len(a)
for key, value in worddictionary.items():
    a.append(key)
    b.append(value)
for i in range(k):
    c[i] = a[i] + '-' + b[i]
    print(c[i])
```

Comment: value of `k` is 0, so, `for i in range(k)` will not be run.

Comment: Your list `c` is empty when you calculate `len(a)`, so `k` is `0`.  It won't change as the list does, you're just storing the number.  You also can't assign to indices that don't already have a value.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: my desired output is [ 'kjnkn'- 4, 'efgrs'-6, 'fgesgv'-7]

Comment: If you expect same order, then `dictionary` do not preserve order.

Comment: `[ 'kjnkn'- 4, 'efgrs'-6, 'fgesgv'-7]` is illegal in Python. The best you can do is `["'kjnkn'- 4", "'efgrs'-6", "'fgesgv'-7"]`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to involve all of these lists.  Generate `c` directly from `worddictionary.items()` using a list comprehension:

```
worddictionary = {'kjnkn':4, 'efgrs':6, 'fgesgv':7}

c = ["'{}'-{}".format(k, v) for k, v in worddictionary.items()]

for i in c:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Sir but i need a different list with its items like [ 'kjnkn'- 4, 'efgrs'-6, 'fgesgv'-7]

Comment: @AdityaShrivastava Is the only difference the quotes around the key?

Comment: May be looking for same order and `dictionary` do not preserve order. In that case `worddictionary` has to be `OrderedDict`